# How to hide navigation parent menu item if one parent menu item contains specific text?

Tags: jquery, html

How do I hide the li with the text "Fish" if the other li contains the text "Turkey | Meats"? I feel like this code should do the trick, but maybe the "|" character in "Turkey | Meats" is causing the code to not work?

Update: I entered the HTML & jQuery incorrectly the first time around. The unique classes are applied to the "li" instead of the "a", and just the second "a" has its own unique class.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  if ($('.nav-a').text() === 'Turkey | Meats') {
    $('.nav-link-1').hide();
  } else {
    $('.nav-link-1').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-link nav-link-1">
      <a href="" class="nav-link">Fish</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link nav-link-2">
      <a href="" class="nav-link nav-a">Turkey | Meats</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.nav-link-1').parent().hide();` - not sure it is worth an answer

Comment: @PraveenKumar, your deleted answer worked, thank you! Adding ".trim()" and removing an additional "=" did the trick.

Comment: @Weebs Lemme undelete. You can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is right, except you should:

1. **Trim the contents.** Mostly the text content will contain a huge number of white-spaces.
2. Not use the strict comparison.
3. Hide or Show the `<li>`.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  if ($('.nav-link-2').text().trim() == 'Turkey | Meats') {
    $('.nav-link-1').parent().hide();
  } else {
    $('.nav-link-1').parent().show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="" class="nav-link-1">Fish</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link">
      <a href="" class="nav-link-2">Turkey | Meats</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Undeleted because of OP's comment: *@PraveenKumar, your deleted answer worked, thank you! Adding ".trim()" and removing an additional "=" did the trick.*